# Retrieving iOS binaries from Apple?

Tags: ios, binaries

Does anyone know if Apple would send me the binaries for our published app upon request? (I thought I would ask on here so to save me potentially wasting a support ticket with Apple.)

The situation is that we need to update our App Store screenshots but don't have access to the source code or binaries at the moment. (It is Apple's requirement that we resubmit the binaries in order to update the screenshots).

Comment: You don't have access to your own source code or any other previous build? Wow.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about The Apple app submission process and not programming.

Comment: I doubt it, I doubt you could use it for submission if they did as well.

Comment: I never said I didn't have access to previous builds. I have access to previous builds, but I do not want to submit a previous build. I want to submit the current build, but I cannot obtain this from my developer for a couple of days. I am therefore asking the question if Apple can provide the binaries. I'm not asking for 'Wow' remarks.

Comment: Even if they could supply the binary, you wouldn't be able to resubmit it because you'd have to make changes to the Info.plist within the bundle which you can't do without re-signing your bundle. You'll just have to wait for your developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the machine from which the binary was submitted, open the Organizer window in Xcode and click on Archives. Here you can see a list of all of the .ipa archives generated by Xcode on that machine. A binary that was uploaded to iTunes Connect will have the word "Submitted" in the status column. The most recent Submitted archive for that app is likely your current store build.

However, you cannot upload the same binary twice due to the restriction that the build number must be incremented by at least one for every new submission. This means that you will need to produce a new binary with an incremented build and version number if you want to make a new iTunes Connect submission and change your screen shots.